# SQL Database Design - Relational or Graph DB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

here's my problem:
I have... "Enterprises" and that enterprises have their own providers, but those providers could have their own providers too and so on..., and also, an enterprise could be a "provider" of another enterprise or provider...

How could I design that on DB? I was thinking about to use graphs databases, but I don't know wheter is a good idea or not..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the options for storing hierarchical data in a relational database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database)

Comment: Even when you have decided on a representation, what will you do with the data?  The `SELECTs` can be messy.